# How to find top radius of Right Truncated Cone?

Tags: trigonometry

Bottom Radius 25mm

Side taper angle 5°

Height 30mm

How to find the Top radius of the the right Right Truncated Cone?

Please help

[image]

Comment: Cut the cone in two equal parts with a vertical cut (seen from above, the cut should be along a diameter of both the top and bottom circle). Draw a drawing of the new cut surface (it should be a trapezium). (Or just draw the cone, as seen exactly from the side. It's the same thing.) Write down all relevant measurements on that drawing. Then see what you can figure out.

Comment: @Arthur please have a look at the above updated question with image now

Comment: Ok, cool. You have tagged this as trigonometry, so you should already know what to look for next: Can you see any right-angled triangles anywhere with either two side lengths known, or an angle and a side length known? It's possible you will have to draw a line or two to make the triangle visible.

Answer (score 1):

The top diameter $d=D-60 \cos 85°$ where $D=25 mm$ is a diameter of the base of the cone. It looks like $d \approx 19.77 mm$.

Comment: Thank you so much...

Comment: Can you explain where is the height value used in this formula?

Comment: Could you please explain

Comment: @Raj33: $2 \cdot 30 =60$. Think of the difference between top and bottom diameter. Draw a rectangle of height $30$ and you will see two pieces that need to be subtracted from the base diameter.